# How to Reset password using passportjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, bcrypt

I am using passportjs to authenticate user and use bcrypt to store password. The following code reset my salt field, but it does not change the hash field.

```
 UserSchema.update({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id.toString()),
    }, {
        $set: {
            salt: req.body.newPassword
        }
    }, function(err, user) {.....}
```

Can any body help me how can i reset the hash field?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm wondering the same thing.

Comment: No I am still looking for it. For now I remove the hash part and working with only salt and encrypt the password with MD5.